# iterator acting weird while in for_each

Tags: c++, foreach, iterator, dereference

Doesn't an iterator have to be deferenced before using? 
I can't understand why

```
for_each(vecResult.begin(), vecResult.end(), [](auto counter) {cout << counter << endl;
});
```

is working (showing the contents of the vector) but

`for_each(vecResult.begin(), vecResult.end(), [](auto counter) {cout << *counter << endl;
});`

is not.(My visual studio shows an error message

```
"'<<':illegal for class)
```

Answer (score 2):

A possible implementation of [`std::for_each`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/for_each) is as follows:

> ```
> template<class InputIt, class UnaryFunction>
> constexpr UnaryFunction for_each(InputIt first, InputIt last, UnaryFunction f)
> {
>     for (; first != last; ++first) {
>         f(*first);
>     }
>     return f; // implicit move since C++11
> }
> ```
>
> <sub>source: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/for_each</sub>

As you can see above, what is passed to the `f` (in your case, the lambda) is already dereferenced. So, in your example `counter` is not an iterator, it's the value to which the iterator points.

Comment: @John If this answers your question, you should press the green tick on the left to mark your problem as solved.